# Имеет ли смысл использовать таблицу БД с 1 столбцом?

Tags: sql, база-данных

По ТЗ необходимо спроектировать БД, состоящую из двух сущностей: 1) Employee; 2) Skill.

Employee имеет атрибуты: id,Name.
Навык имеет атрибуты: Name, Level(уровень владения).

На данный момент использую связь между таблицами многие ко многим, перенеся атрибут Level в соединяющую таблицу. Получается таблица Skill будет иметь 1 атрибут - Name, он же будет и первичным ключом. Вопрос в том, насколько это правильно? Может есть альтернативные варианты?

Comment: "Может есть альтернативные варианты" --- ну например в Employee иметь колонку skills с типом "перечисление" и тогда никакие промежуточные таблицы не нужны.....а так...ну норм...

Comment: *Получается таблица Skill будет иметь 1 атрибут - Name, он же будет и первичным ключом.* Name - строковый. Первичный индекс-строка - вообще-то плохо.

Comment: Подумайте что случится когда вы решите поменять название скилла